# How to prove the converse of Vitali Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The converse of Vitali Theorem says:

Suppose $(X,\mu)$ is a measurable space. If $\mu(X)<\infty$ and $\{f_n\}\subset L^1(X,\mu)$. For each measurable set $E$, $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_E f_n\mathrm{d}\mu$ exists. Then $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly integrable.

Here we say $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly integrable if for each $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$ \mu(A)<\delta \Rightarrow \int_A \vert f_n\vert \mathrm{d}\mu<\epsilon, n\geq 1$$

I tried to use the Cauchy convergence theorem and the fact: if $f\in L^1(X,\mu)$, for each $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$ \mu(A)<\delta \Rightarrow \int_A \vert f\vert \mathrm{d}\mu<\epsilon$$
But I don't know how to use to condition $\mu(X)<\infty$. I hope if someone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: @saz I mean the former one, and I have edited my description.

Comment: You can find a proof in *Measure Theory* by V. Bogachev; this is Theorem 4.5.6.  The proof uses a rather involved Baire category argument.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge Thanks!